# Downgrade XServer 1.19 to 1.10

Tags: kali-linux, x-server, amd-graphics, radeon, ati

When I try to install AMD Catalyst to my Kali Linux 2.0 detailed as below

```
root@blackbox:~/Downloads/fglrx-15.302# uname -a
Linux blackbox 4.9.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.13-1kali3 (2017-03-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I get this following error.

```
error: Detected X Server version 'XServer 1.19.2_64a' is not supported. Supported versions are X.Org 6.9 or later, up to XServer 1.10 (default:v2:x86_64:lib32:XServer 1.19.2_64a:none:4.9.0-kali3-amd64:)
Installation will not proceed.
```

And no new updated drivers were found in AMD's website. So I would like to downgrade my XServer to supported version. How do I do this?

Details on my dedicated graphics card as below

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
        !!! Unknown header type 7f
        Kernel driver in use: radeon
        Kernel modules: radeon
```

And is there a way to find out that the current generic driver supports automatic switchable graphics? And is there a way to find it?

P.S
I am relatively new to Linux. So please go easy on me.Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

You don’t want to downgrade your X server; you’ll just have to stick with the `radeon` driver (which is actually pretty good).

I would suggest you try a different distribution though since you’re new to Linux; as the [Kali documentation explains](http://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux),

> Kali is a Linux distribution specifically geared towards professional penetration testers and security specialists, and given its unique nature, it is **NOT** a recommended distribution if you’re unfamiliar with Linux

Comment: Ty for your suggestion. Just tell me how to check if the GPU is configured correctly to handle intensive tasks. I am thinking of installing a heavy game to check if it works without breaking. Any simpler alternatives?

Comment: Presumably you have something in mind you want to run, right? Just try running that; if it works, good and well, otherwise you can ask more specific questions.

Comment: @wishchaser The benchmarks based on the Unity engine can be a good place to start: https://benchmark.unigine.com